# In unityscript, get the distinct words in a set of Strings in an array

Tags: string, loops, unity-game-engine, distinct, unityscript

So I have an array that looks like this:

```
var questans = new String[10, 2];
questans[0,0]="Hey How's it going?";  
questans[0,1]="You know me Just chillin'";
questans[1,0]="Hello there friend";
questans[1,1]="Well met to you too!";
questans[2,0]="I like chocolate pudding";
questans[2,1]="Good for you";
```

I need to essentially extract all the words from it. I tried writing a for loop, but it kept giving me some weird errors.

I've currently got code down to finding the total number of distinct words:

```
var ff: String[questans.Length]; //Returned string array
var linenumber = 0; //Current line, 0-index
var spacecount = 0; //Current space in current line, 0-index
for (var line in questans) {
    for (var spaceSplit in line.Split(" ")) {
        ff[linenumber, spacecount] =  spaceSplit[spacecount];
        spacecount++;
    }
    spacecount = 0;
    linenumber++;
}
```

But I'm having problem with obtaining all the words out of the array given above. Please help me out with this problem.

Comment: `new String[10, 2]`?, `var ff: String[questans.Length]` ??, `line.Split(" ")`??? All of those look like invalid JS syntax.

Comment: Also, aside from the not so obvious `Split` problem, this `for (var spaceSplit in line.Split(" "))` is trouble; better to loop arrays with a regular `for` loop, same with the `questans` "array"... The code looks all messy, better start from scratch.

Comment: `questans[0,0]=...;` just in addition to elclanrs's list.

Answer (score 2):

Other than what @eclanrs has pointed out, here is what is wrong:

- JS does not support the `[x,y]` syntax for multidimensional array access. You have to use nested arrays. `arr[x,y]` just becomes equivalent to `arr[y]`
- `for (var line in questans) {` is not the correct way to iterate over arrays, since you will get all the properties inherited from the prototype as well
- JS is case sensitive, and most properties are camel-cased. `questans.Length` needs to be `questans.length`, and `line.Split` needs to be `line.split`

I suggest you read some JS tutorials to get started, otherwise you'll find yourself lost.

Comment: Hey.. Sorry, I believe that is C# syntax... I mostly put it up as a reference.. I need to basically do something similar in Javascript.. Sorry if I confused you guys!

Comment: @gran_profaci Actually it looks very much like UnityScript, not JavaScript.